# bad request error with polymer component POST function

Tags: ajax, post, request, polymer, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to create a Polymer component that make a simple POST httprequest.

```
<link rel="import" href="/components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">

<polymer-element name="test-insert">
  <template>

   <core-ajax auto method="POST" contentType="application/json"  url="/api/accounts" body='{"email":user@example.com}'>
</core-ajax>
</template>
```

This is the , i get always a ERR 400, BAD REQUEST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body='{"email":user@example.com}'` should be `body='{"email":"user@example.com"}'`. Note the quotes around the email.